# Can't connect Tor Network, failed to establish network. connection failed (done - 46.4.111.124:9001)

Tags: configuration

I'm getting this error and Tor is sticking on 10% then fails with the message
'Can't connect Tor Network, failed to establish network. Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done - 46.4.111.124:9001)'. How can I fix this?

```
06/02/2017 10:28:32.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/02/2017 10:28:32.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/02/2017 10:28:32.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/02/2017 10:28:32.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/02/2017 10:28:32.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
06/02/2017 10:28:33.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
06/02/2017 10:30:03.700 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 7EA6EAD6FD83083C538F44038BBFA077587DD755 at 194.109.206.212:443) 
06/02/2017 10:30:03.700 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
06/02/2017 10:30:03.700 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/02/2017 10:30:09.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/02/2017 10:30:09.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/02/2017 10:30:09.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/02/2017 10:30:09.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: Please provide the actual log rather than part of 1 line.

Comment: Have edited post with log file

Comment: Looks like censorship or an incredibly bad connection. Use bridges with pluggable transports.

Answer (score 0):

it is censorship, 99% sure because of `X connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE` string in log. You need to use bridges *with* pluggable transport - try meek transport, it's designed specially for such a cases